# c# - 'input string was not in a correct format' when parsing integers

Tags: c#, mysql

Okay, so i'm trying to get 18 "prices" from my database in SQL, then setting them in a local array. So far i have this logic in the data retrieval:

```
private void dbPrices()
{
    string myConnectionString;

    myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
        "pwd=;database=phvpos";

    try
    {
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price from products where id = '" + i + "'";

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            pr[i] = reader.ToString();
            prods[i] = int.Parse(pr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this logic in getting the total amount:

```
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbPrices();

    itemcost[0] = Convert.ToInt32(txtRice.Text) * prods[0];
    itemcost[1] = Convert.ToInt32(txtAdobo.Text) * prods[1];
    itemcost[2] = Convert.ToInt32(txtIgado.Text) * prods[2];
    itemcost[3] = Convert.ToInt32(txtSisig.Text) * prods[3];
    ...
    itemcost[18] = itemcost[0] + itemcost[1] + itemcost[2] + itemcost[3] + itemcost[4] + itemcost[5]
        + itemcost[6] + itemcost[7] + itemcost[8] + itemcost[9] + itemcost[10]
        + itemcost[11] + itemcost[12] + itemcost[13] + itemcost[14] + itemcost[15]
        + itemcost[16] + itemcost[17];

    int totalPrice = itemcost[18];

    lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(totalPrice);
}
```

this line in dbPrices() spits out a 'input string was not in a correct format' error:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    pr[i] = reader.ToString();
    prods[i] = int.Parse(pr[i]);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    prods[i] = Convert.toInt32(reader.ToString());
}
```

But also spits the same error. Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use `reader.GetInt32(0)`? There is no need to convert the int to a string first. If `price` is a `decimal` use `reader.GetDecimal`.

Comment: Have you debuged and checked what's the value of `reader.ToString()` when you convert it to an int? It's impossible to give an answer without knowing the data...

Comment: the prices in the integer are "int"

Comment: `reader.ToString()` doesn't specify which column you want the value of. When you buy a pair of shoes, you take each shoe out of the box and put it on the appropriate foot, you don't take the whole box with the shoes in it and try to wear that. You need to tell the reader that you want the value of column 0.

Comment: I see no indication that you made any attempt to find out what `reader.ToString()` is returning. Why didn't you do that? You get an exception that says "the value you passed here is wrong" -- aren't you the least bit curious at all about what the value might be or what might be wrong with it? You just *assumed* that the one thing the error told you was wrong, is the one thing you don't need to worry about. Well, now you know.

Comment: Why not optimize the query?  `SELECT price FROM products WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 18` this way you fetch all 19 prices without needing the for loop... and you should let the database handle the sum.. `SELECT SUM(price) as total_price FROM products WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 18`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value from your result needs to convert to int and your for loop block might cause you serious problem in the future, you might want to have a projection query and then assign the values of the result.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT price FROM products WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 18"; //use projection. if you have a dynamic product id set, you can use IN in query.
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var counter = 0; //counter
while (reader.Read())
{   
    prods[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["price"]); //convert the result first then assign it to the item.
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I find that when using 'reader' that even when your query only grabs one value you still need to specify what value your looking for.

```
prods[i] = int.Parse(reader["price"]);
```

and if price is nullable in the database use a ternary operator

```
prods[i] = reader["price"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : int.parse(reader["price"]);
```